# Does a CLR stored procedure for SQL Server need to access the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

Currently I'm in a bit of a sticky situation where we can't get access to an external database and instead are pulling the data via their REST API. This data needs to be pulled prior to the execution of a stored procedure that performs analysis on the external data and our own.

My idea is to create a CLR stored procedure that would be called by the stored procedure doing the analysis which would run HTTP requests, deserialize the JSON, then stuff the data into our database.

Are there any potential timeout errors? Does a CLR stored procedure need to be pure HttpClient code? Why is this idea so terrible that I felt the need to confirm it with y'all on StackOverflow?

Thanks

Comment: Dunno if it's so terrible, but I'd look into using SSIS instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good candidate for using SQL Server Service Broker.  The procedure call could simply put a message on a service queue.  You could then create a program that is activated when a message arrives to pull the requested data from the API and then responds with a message when it's done or errors out.  It also allows you to offload the API work from your SQL server if needed.  It's an Asynchronous solution, so whatever program is calling the procedure can do other work while it's waiting for the results if needed.